# Несколько форм "обратных связей" на странице

Tags: php, html

Такая проблема, на странице есть блоки, списки и текстовые поля для ввода пользователем и отправки на почту. Вот пример:

```
<!-- Форма 1 / Sample 1 -->
<form action="thank-you.php" name="form1">  
    <select name="sample1">
        <option value="s1">А</option>
        <option value="s2">Б</option>
        <option value="s3">В</option>
    </select>
</form>

    <p>Email</p>
        <input type="text" name="sample1" id="email">

    <p>Phone</p>
        <input type="text" name="sample1" id="phone">

    <input type="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" class="submit" id="submit">



<!-- Форма 2 / Sample 2 -->
<form action="thank-you.php" name="form2">  
    <select name="sample2">
        <option value="s1">А</option>
        <option value="s2">Б</option>
        <option value="s3">В</option>
    </select>
</form>

    <p>Email</p>
        <input type="text" name="sample2" id="email">

    <p>Phone</p>
        <input type="text" name="sample2" id="phone">

    <input type="submit" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" class="submit" id="submit">
```

2 вопроса:

1)Как сделать что бы при отправке эти 2 формы, которые находятся на одной странице не были связаны между собой, и отправлялись по отдельности?

2)Как это всё преобразовать как в самом документе html, так и в php-файле (thank-you.php)? чтобы всё связано было, и данные отправлялись на почту.

Comment: На сервер отправляется содержимое той формы, для которой сработал submit. То есть то, что расположено в рамках `<form></form>`  но в вашем случае `<input type="submit">` находится вне форм, и что он передаёт - вообще непонятно.

Comment: @iosp, ну это я понял, а в остальном как? по коду и в файле php?